# Signal handling in C - SIGTSTP not behaving as expected

Tags: c, signals, signal-handling

I am having issues handling SIGTSTP signal. In my code, SIGINT and SIGTSTP are only supposed to affect the child process. When Control+\ is pressed (SIGQUIT), then the program (both child and parent) is supposed to terminate. SIGINT and SIGQUIT are both working fine but I can't figure out why SIGTSTP is not. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
void sigint_handler(long getpid, int signum) {
       kill(getpid, signum);
}


void sigtstp_handler (long getpid, int signum) {
      kill(getpid, signum);
      printf("The process has been stopped");
}
```

.

```
pid = fork();
if (pid == 0) { /* this is child process */
    signal(SIGINT, sigint_handler);
    signal(SIGTSTP, sigtstp_handler);
    execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
perror("execvp");
exit(-1);
```

Comment: What kind of system is that? The signal handler takes a single argument. Also 1) use sigaction(2) instead of signal(2) 2) don't use printf() from a signal handler 3) post something reproducible, not "pseudocode"

Comment: It's a linux system. Thank you for the comments. I cant post the entire code because it's a part of the assignment.